# "handlebars.registerHelper is not a function"

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I want to create a simple reverse handlebars helper, but on app.js running, I have this error:

```
TypeError: exphbs.registerHelper is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\test\login\server\example.js:7:8)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:752:3)
```

Thank you very much
Nathan

Comment: Follow the stack trace and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

```
const exphbs = require('exphbs');
```

To manually register a helper, use this:

```
const handlebars = exphbs.handlebars;

handlebars.registerHelper('hello', function() {
  return new handlebars.SafeString('Hello!');
});
```

Taken from [the fine manual](https://github.com/gnowoel/exphbs/blob/master/docs/helpers.md#manually-registering).